# Attach (Child)Rigidbody TO (Parent)Rigidbody let it collide with Tilemap

Tags: physics

We want to attach a (Child)Rigidbody to another (Parent)Rigidbody
so that the (Child)Rigidbody is also transformed on (Parent)Rigidbody transformation.

The other constrain is that the (Parent)Rigidbody contains a tilemap also with collisions.

So we want the (Child)Rigidbody to:

- inherits the (Parent)Rigidbody transformation when it is ON the (Parent)Rigidbody
- collide with the tilemap ON the (Parent)Rigidbody
- be able to leave the (Parent)Rigidbody and move freely in the world space.

During our tests, no game or physic-engine is able to do this.
Eg.

- Box2d

  - is not able to transform a world
  - applying parent forces to the child gives inacurate results
- Unity

  - "nearly" can do it with (Parent)Rigidbody->Static Tilemap
    but transforming the Static Tilemap gives inacurate results.
- Godot

  - "nearly" can do it, the same way as unity, but also gives inacurate results,
    when moveing Static Tilemaps. Also some (already reported) physic bugs renders godot unsuited.

We already consider to build a custom physic engine, but this will be a huge task we like to avoid.

We are searching for a way to do this, if you know an physic engine that supports this please speak up :).

Comment: Can you explain a bit of the context for why you need this feature? Many games that seem to do something like this in fact accomplish the outcome in a different way, so there may be other routes to get the gameplay you want.

Comment: The idea is to be a character on a starship, the ship should have an interior, the player moves and interact with the interior, the player controls the spaceship from within.
Other ships / bodies should be able to enter and leave a spaceship freely.

Comment: This is normally accomplished by having one physics environment for the stuff in the (stationary) ship, and a second for the (moving) ship in space and other bodies around it. Entering/exiting is handled like a portal under the hood, and the two physics environments are drawn in perfect alignment so it's seamless to the player.

Comment: yeah we thought about projecting the interior useing a viewport to the ship (and we also build a demo useing this technique with unity). But it seems that unity cannot do multiple physic environments, so one issue with unity is how to seperate both "worlds". We thought about putting them to different z-layers, or have a seperate area in the world only used for the interior that cannot be reached any other ways.
Box2d on the other hand, can create different worlds, so either make this work with unity, or upgrading our custom engine to do this... *scratch head*

Comment: Sure Unity can do that, just put them on separate physics layers, and swap layers when traveling through the portal. Instead of asking about a relatively obscure physics engine feature, want to edit your question to ask "How to support physics entities inside a moving ship?" or something like that? Then you can get answers that solve the problem through alternative means, not just the one you've thought of. [This helps avoid the X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, but i must admit, during our research we saw a lot of similar issues be it in 2d or 3d. In my opinion, this is not so obscure since a lot people want this behavior, but a limitation in the current physic engine world.

Comment: I'd say it's a limitation in how you're conceiving of the problem. It's fully solvable with existing physics engine tools, which is why you don't find physics engines going out of their way to make separate features just for this.

Comment: Note that you can have distinct physics worlds in Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PhysicsScene.html